# How can I create a path for file.write to follow when opening a file in append

Tags: python

am trying to use file.write() to write the results of a score-calculating program into a file named Score.txt but when it is run the file is left blank, **How can I find where a text file is being created or specify the path it should take to write the text file?**

The file is stored in the same folder as the text file I am trying to edit
f= open("Score.txt", "a")

```
country = input('what country?\n')
gold = int(input('how many gold medals does the country have?\n'))
gold=gold*3
silver =int(input('how many silver medals does the country have?\n'))
silver=silver*2
bronze = int(input('how many bronze medals does the country have?\n'))
total = gold + silver + bronze
total = str(total)
print(country, 'got', total)
f.write('\n')
f.write(country)
f.write('\n')
f.write('\n = \n')
f.write('\n')
f.write(total)
f.write('\n')
f.write('test')
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The text file should be created in the same directory that you are running your python script.

This is because you haven't changed the path of your  `f= open("Score.txt", "a")`

You can also declare a relative path or absolute path to your Score.txt file.

**Absolute path**
open  Score.txt from an absolute location

`f = open(r"C:\my_programs\Score.txt","a")`

**Relative Path**
open myFile from the parent directory of current python script.

`f = open("../Score.txt","a")`